# Securely send data from Raspberry Pi to Apache Server

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, apache

Raspberry Pi - collects temperature data and stores in a file

Server - Apache, on VM, hosts website (HTML, PHP + JavaScript) with graph of some data

I need to securely send the data file from the Pi to the server, which will use that data file to populate the graph on the website.

What the best the easiest way to accomplish this?

I am relatively new to everything related to this, and have done so much reading and testing, but can't seem to figure out how to properly do this.

I have two sets of code for the graph, one that uses an SQLite database (ideal) and one that uses a JSON file (works but not the most ideal). Both just use the files stored locally currently.

Comment: By *send data* you mean which protocol? Rest, http...

Comment: Anything, even if it doesn't need a sever on the Pi. Just need to repeatedly send the data being continuously created on the Pi to the server, which it can then use to populate the graph.

Comment: I would recommend using `csync` to transfer the files periodically using a cron.

Comment: Your last paragraph of `P.S. If the best method is to not e` seems to be unfinished?

Comment: Hi chivs890. I see you signed in today. I have downvoted this question because my request for improvement has been ignored. Please be willing to keep questions in a good state.

Answer (score 0):

Run an HTTPS web service on Server B which requires Server A to send a username / password along with the data.

Comment: Is there something you could point me towards to be able to implement this as a beginner? What you say there sounds like it could be what I need, but I would have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Pick a web server. Read its docs to find out how to configure HTTPS for it. Pick a programming language. Write server-side code to process the request with the data in it. Both topics are rather too broad to cover in a SO question.

Comment: I've already got a HTTPS Apache server up and running (Server B). Currently hosts a PHP file with HTML, PHP and JavaScript code making it up. Have used AJAX within it to repeatedly run a separate PHP file stored locally. The only bit I'm stuck on it the "Write server-side code to process the request with the data in it." as I don't know what to write on the Raspberry Pi side or within the Server side to send and receive the data.

Comment: To use HTTPS you need an SSL certificate. If you do shared hosting with some hosting provider, often times they will include a free SSL for your site

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can create VPN between both machines.

Depends on the data sensitivity, HTTPS may be enough + some kind of the API with additional authorization.

---

***VERY BASIC IMPLEMENTATION***

***Apache Server Side***

**save.php:**

```
<?php
    $temperature = $_GET['temperature'];
    $timestamp = $_GET['timestamp'];
    // INSERT into database
    // or
    // save in the file
```

***Pi SIDE***

I don't know what language you are using in the Pi side, but what you could do is execting HTTP GET request like: `https://your.server.ip.or.domain/save.php?temperature=N&timestamp=999999999`

If possible (Pi has fixed IP), you can filter the request based on it. It will make it more secure.

Comment: Data isn't super sensitive, just would rather it not be completely insecure. At this stage would just be happy to get the function of it sending the data working, if I was able to then make it secure later. HTTPS would be plenty fine. Based on that, would you be able to give any more specifics on what I could do?

Comment: @chivs890 How often the temperature is measured and saved in the file? How often do you want to send data to server from the raspberry device?

Comment: It is collecting data every 10 seconds currently, so pretty frequently.

Comment: @chivs890 based on all the other comments, I understand that your main expectation is to make something that works with basic security. I updated the answer, so hopefully it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make the PI save the temperature data to a simple local file. (ideally in a memory hosted partition as SD cards do wear out.)

Configure a sftp server on the PI.

Then on the web server pull the file from PHP with

```
file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$user}:{$pass}@{$pi_ip}:22{$pi_path}"))
```

And process it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed by many others HTTPS server will be a good start, if you have a registered domain name for your server you can use https://letsencrypt.org/ which provides a handy script **certbot** that will allow you to convert your existing setup to https.

In case you don't have a registered domain, you can self sign a SSL certificate (simple Google will point you to the required resources) and use the same to enable HTTPS on your Apache server.

Comment: The server is actually already fully HTTPS equipped, and using my own personal domain, which all works perfectly. Just need to get the sending of data from the Pi to the server then the goal of my project is complete.

Comment: You can run any setup eg: Apache+PHP/Tomcat etc. on server side with an end-point where you can make a POST call (https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/#post) and send the data in JSON or other format. The data can be then processed on the server side.